# C# some public properties are not accessible, actually completely missing

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, properties, public

I have a bizarre problem with a simple class that has 3 public properties. For some reason, only 2 of the properties "exist" even though the code that defines them is identical.

Elsewhere in the code I'm binding to these 3 properties, 2 of the properties work (metric & weightUnits), but "distanceUnits" does not.

When I put a breakpoint on the code where this class is instantiated, and hover over the object, only "metric" and "weightUnits" show up as public properties and when I expand "non-public members", everything is there but "distanceUnits" is still missing.

Debugger screen shot:

[image]

```
public class AppGlobalSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _metric;
    public bool metric
    {
        get { return _metric; }
        set {
            _metric = value;
            if (_metric) {
                distanceUnits = "cm";
                weightUnits = "Kg";
            }
            else {
                distanceUnits = "in.";
                weightUnits = "lbs";
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _weightUnits;
    public string weightUnits { get { return _weightUnits; } set { _weightUnits = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

    private string _distanceUnits;
    public string distanceUnits { get { return _distanceUnits; } set { _distanceUnits = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
...
}
```

The only wrinkle I can think of is that the object is instantiated as "public static (see below), but that wouldn't explain why only some properties are available...

```
public class App : Application
{
    public static AppGlobalSettings appSettings;
    public App() {
        appSettings = new AppGlobalSettings();
        appSettings.distanceUnits = "in."; // ** just for debugging **
...
}
```

I know the property "exists" and is public because I put in debugging code (as noted above) and it works (it does indeed call the "set" method of "distanceUnits") but it does not show up in the debugger and the binding doesn't work.

For the sake of completeness, here is the binding code for the labels that shows distanceUnits:

```
        Binding girthUnitBinding = new Binding("distanceUnits");
        girthUnitBinding.Source = App.appSettings;
        girthCell.unitLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, girthUnitBinding);
```

And in that section, if I edit "distanceUnits" to "weightUnits" just as a test, the binding works.

So any idea why the propertyChanged handler and the debugger can see "weightUnits" but not "distanceUnits" ?

Comment: Did you try a clean build and restart VS?

Comment: Yes I did try "build->clean solution", and restarted VS. I just did it again to be sure. No change. Are there any other "rebuild" or "clean" type procedures that could be tried?

Comment: Not that I've ever heard of. Is `AppGlobalSettings` in the same assembly as the `App` class?

Comment: I don't know how to check that? I'm new to C# and Visual Studio. On a side note, as a test I created an entirely new class and instantiated it as a static in the same way. When I debug, none of the properties show up so that seems to rule out a compiler issue. I'm thinking it has something to do with it being static. Maybe the properties have to be instantiated or something...

Comment: Is it in the same project, I mean?

Comment: Nothing to do with the instance being static, that makes no sense. Not a chance. Also I tested your exact code and it didn't reproduce. Nothing about instantiating properties; you really mean initializing, right? But no, the debugger sees them whether initialized or not.

Comment: This is the debugger behaving weirdly. The usual reason for this is the debugger is running a stale copy of the EXE (or DLL, whichever).

Comment: Yes it's all in the same project. But it's not just the debugger, the data binding also doesn't work. Does "clean" clear out the stale exe or dll ?

Comment: Clean should delete all stale executables, but at times it doesn't, e.g. if you've got web services running locally, or it's a full moon. "Running in the debugger" means the actual executable actually running, including bindings. It can be stale relative to the code in the editor that you're stepping through. My (very shaky) hypothesis is something like, you added `distanceUnits` last and it's running a copy of the binary that doesn't include it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just to try and rule out every possibility I can think of, I created a new class "TestSettings" which is a simplified version of the original class. I then initialized it in the same way and the debugger doesn't see _any_ of the public properties (but it does show the private ones). BTW, this is an android app developed with Xamarin debugging in the emulator. Maybe it's pushing some stale code over to the emulator..

Comment: OMG Xamarin emulator -- you need to talk to somebody who really knows that stuff. I added the Xamarin tag to the question. I'm sorry, this question is way out of my lane.

Comment: Ok, my project must be completely screwed up... I commented out the problem class and created one new from scratch. When I debugged a breakpoint that was still set on a commented line in the old class _STILL_ broke execution. So ya, something stale or whatever is causing it to run old code. I think this requires a new question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Such as it was. But yeah, wandering breakpoints are a key symptom of stale binaries. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments from Ed Plunkett about this actually being a build/debug issue, I was able to find a solution to this problem so I thought I'd answer my own question just in case anyone stumbles on this thread even though the original question and the final answer seem totally unrelated.

My solution was inspired by this post:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45327/newest-version-of-code-not-always-deployed-when-debugging-from-xamarin-studio

In short:

1. Shutdown Visual Studio
2. Open windows explorer and navigate to your solution folder
3. Delete the contents of each of these folders:

   - Release/obj
   - Release/bin
   - Debug/bin
   - Debug/obj
4. If your solution has multiple projects, for example if you are developing cross-platform solutions using Xamarin, you'll potentially need to do this for each project folder in the solution, e.g.:

   - projectname
   - projectname.Droid
   - projectname.iOS
   - etc.

Note: You would think that "Build -> Clean Solution" (or similar) would do this for you but it does not. You have to go in manually and delete the files yourself.

Hope this helps someone and thanks again to Ed for starting me down the right path.